# requirejs - underscore module not loaded

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

Seeing error - I'm not sure what exactly is wrong. Page/Modules loads sometimes but many a times I get this error. This is with latest underscore and backbone modules.

> Error: Module name 'underscore' has not been loaded yet for context: _ 
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

```
require.config({
"baseUrl": "js",
"paths": {       
  "jquery":"libs/jquery-1.8.2",      
  "underscore":"libs/underscore-min",
  "backbone":"libs/backbone-min",
  },
shim: {
    'backbone': {            
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    }        
  } // end Shim Configuration    
});

require(['jquery', 'underscore','backbone'], function($, _, Backbone){  
   console.log('require init - ' + Backbone + ", " + _);

});
```

Comment: Are you using it in any define calls? The errors suggests incorrect usage of `require` somewhere

Comment: yeah, I read err and checked, it is not in define calls.

Answer (score 3):

Try with **underscore-amd** version. Here is my  require config and it works great:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "handlebars": "./libs/handlebars/handlebars",
        "jquery": "./libs/jquery/jquery",
        "underscore": "./libs/underscore-amd/underscore",
        "backbone": "./libs/backbone-amd/backbone"
    },

    shim: {
        "backbone": {
            exports: "backbone"
        },

        "Handlebars": {
            exports:"Handlebars"
        },

        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see I don't have base url and deps - require will find dependencies by the provided paths.

Comment: i changed to amd backbone and underscore and it just works, without shim config. thanks.